# Issue with tikz UML and accents

Tags: accents, tikz-uml

I have an issue using tikzuml and accents. The following works fine:

```
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
...
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{umlsystem}{e}
\umlusecase{{\'e}}
\end{umlsystem}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

while the following does not (only the \umlcase line differs):

```
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
...
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{umlsystem}{{\'e}}
\umlusecase{{\'e}}
\end{umlsystem}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I get an error : "Missing \endcsname inserted". So it seems that there is a problem with using accents with the "umlsystem" environment.

Does anyone knows how to fix this issue ?

Comment: I filed a bug report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package uses the argument to `umlsystm` also for forming node names, where accented characters are invalid.

You can patch it (and suggest the authors to do something similar) by storing also a “stringified” version of the argument to be used for node names.

It's easier using `regexpatch` than `xpatch`, because the second patch must be applied nine times.

Basically, each of the nine occurrences of `\tikzumlSystemName-` and the single `(\tikzumlSystemName)` should be replaced with `\tikzumlSystemNameLabel-` or `(\tikzumlSystemName)`; the definition of `\tikzumlSystemNameLabel` is added at the start of the environment: it uses `\detokenize` to get a string, as opposed to printable characters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\usepackage{regexpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\umlsystem}
  {\def\tikzumlSystemName}
  {\edef\tikzumlSystemNameLabel{\detokenize{#2}}\def\tikzumlSystemName}
  {}{}
\xpatchcmd*{\endumlsystem}
  {\tikzumlSystemName-}
  {\tikzumlSystemNameLabel-}
  {}{}
\xpatchcmd*{\endumlsystem}
  {(\tikzumlSystemName)}
  {(\tikzumlSystemNameLabel)}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{umlsystem}{{\'e}}
\umlusecase{{\'e}}
\end{umlsystem}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{umlsystem}{é}
\umlusecase{é}
\end{umlsystem}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

You can also use directly the accented characters, as shown in the second example. Here I used `utf8`, but it works also with `latin1`.

[image]